# Expressão regular capturando toda linha

Tags: regex

Preciso que uma expressão intercepte todo o conteúdo de uma linha, começando por uma palavra específica e indo até a quebra da linha. Neste trecho poderá ocorrer de tudo, preciso que identifique tudo sem discriminação.

Resumindo, sei como começa a linha e quero todo o resto até a quebra da linha.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer assim:

```
^palavra.+
```

Onde palavra é o começo da linha que você deseja pegar.

Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/LV4gzk/1

Comment: Muito obrigada! Imaginei que fosse bem simples, porém quebrei a cabeça e não havia conseguido. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @RenattaSantos Favor ler [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/75104)